# ViewModel cannot be instantiated in Fragment

Tags: android

I am trying to instantiate one ViewModel to use across all my fragments, to update all the visible fragments recyclerview, but what I get is this follwing error `ReleasesViewModel releasesViewModel = ReleasesViewModel.of(this).get(ReleasesViewModel.class);`

The `of` method cannot be resolved.

```
public class UpcomingViewPagerFragment extends Fragment implements Observable {

    private static final String TAG = UpcomingGamesFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    public ViewPager mViewPager;
    private List<Observer> mObserversList = new ArrayList<>();
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    public UpcomingViewPagerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upcoming_view_pager, container, false);
        // Viewpager
        mViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        // Get the ViewModel
        ReleasesViewModel releasesViewModel = ReleasesViewModel.of(this).get(ReleasesViewModel.class);
```

Code was omitted for clarity.
Both of my fragments are `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` for both of fragments.

Here's my viewmodel livedata class

```
public class ReleasesViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<List<UpcomingGamesFragment>> upcomingFragmentLiveData =
            new MutableLiveData<>();

    public ReleasesViewModel() {

    }

    public LiveData<List<UpcomingGamesFragment>> getUpcomingFragmentList() {
        return upcomingFragmentLiveData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no method `of` on your `ViewModel` implementation, as this method comes from the `ViewModelProviders` class ;-)

So change your code from:

```
ReleasesViewModel releasesViewModel = ReleasesViewModel.of(this).get(ReleasesViewModel.class);
```

To:

```
ReleasesViewModel releasesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ReleasesViewModel.class);
```

That should fix the issue.

See: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel for more info.

Comment: ViewModeProviders is now deprecated